# IE7 problems

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-7

I'm working on a website with simple jquery effects, like show, hide...

http://emilione.altervista.org/works.html

This page works well with IE8, FF3.6 and Chrome 5, but there are some problems with IE7.

How to reproduce the problem:

-click on "x" thumb -> the content relative to the thumb is shown
-click on the same thumb -> content disappear
-click on "y" thumb -> content "x" and "y" appear together overlying ("x" image with "x" text and "y" image with "y" text)

Error preview: yfrog.com/ngproblemaxj (with http://)

If it's not clear, I want to show 1 image with corresponding text individually.
In linked screenshot you can see two images, one above the other!

With IE8 developer tools (IE7 browser mode) css diplay property seems to be set correctly but I notice the presence of "jQuery1281468352670", "sizcache" and "sizset" attributes in html view.

I'm not able to find a solution and I hope for your help especially for "Preview()" function in "works.js" file.

Thanks

(Sorry for my poor english)

Comment: Is this a fair summary?  In non-IE7 browsers, text pops up _beside_ the image.  In IE7, the text pops up _on top of_ the image.

Comment: Ok, this is a CSS issue; I believe that my main problem regards jquery code and .show() - .hide() method or wrong use of selectors.
Anyway thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, it looks like you have `.desc` set as such:

```
.desc {
    width: 50px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

However, this is not enough to contain the content, so browsers have to guess. Modern browsers will guess correctly, IE7 will not. Try the following instead:

```
.desc {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto; /* Or just leave the height out entirely */
}
```

As far as my testing goes, this should solve your IE7 issues, and have no effect on more modern browsers.

**Update**

As for the jQuery show/hide issue, my best guess is as follows. And it is *a guess*.

I think you should try reversing the lines

```
$("#works").hide();
$("div","#works").hide();
```

It's *possible* that, in the second line, IE (6 for me, 7 for you), looks at the `div`s in `#works`, and since `#works` is already hidden, interprets them as hidden as well, and so doesn't bother to set their display values. Then, when you click another item, `#works` is shown again, with the old item still visible.

This is pure speculation, as I haven't been able to duplicate the bug under simpler circumstance, but it's my best guess.

Comment: Thank you, this resolve my CSS issue!
My main problem however still occurs. Please try to see a screenshot that point out the problem: http://yfrog.com/joerrorpreviewj

Comment: I'm not seeing this issue in IE7. I am seeing it in IE6.

Comment: Updated with a guess as to what's happening.

Comment: Great!! Your guess is the solution! Now I can try to improve my js functions. Thank you very much!